# How to make SFINAE work with template specializations?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I have a template method `foo`. I would like to have several different implementations: for `T`, `vector<T>` and `vector<vector<T>>` where `T` is a built-in type or some complex class. I would like to use SFINAE to separate implementations for built-in types and classes and restrict a set of allowable types.

The following code works correctly but I get warning messages:

```
8:37: warning: inline function 'constexpr bool isType() [with T =
 std::vector<int>]' used but never defined

8:37: warning: inline function 'constexpr bool isType() [with T =
 std::vector<std::vector<int> >]' used but never defined
```

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ComplexClass{};

template<typename T> constexpr bool isType();
template<> constexpr bool isType<int>()  {return true;}
template<> constexpr bool isType<ComplexClass>() {return false;}

template <typename T>
inline typename enable_if<isType<T>(), void>::type
foo(T& value) {}

template <typename T>
inline typename enable_if<!isType<T>(), void>::type
foo(T& value) {}

template <typename T>
inline typename enable_if<isType<T>(), void>::type
foo(vector<T>& value) {}

template <typename T>
inline typename enable_if<isType<T>(), void>::type
foo(vector<vector<T>>& value) {}

int main()
{
    int a;
    vector<int> b;
    vector<vector<int>> c;
    ComplexClass d;
    char e;
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
    foo(d);
//    foo(e); // has to lead to an error
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like compiler tries to pass `vector<...>` into the first `enable_if` method and fails. But it would be great to skip such methods because we have better candidates for `vector<T>` and `vector<vector<T>>`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I would go with partial specializations (and put functions in the class for that). Way easier than SFINAE.

Comment: If I understood correctly, is this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eRVkR4R58ezSAWhL not what you want? neglect the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to limit the vector overloaded function templates to accept vectors of built-in types only. Otherwise those overloads do not need SFINAE.

You can also use [`std::is_fundamental`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental) to detect built-in types:

Working example:

```
using namespace std;

class ComplexClass {};

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
foo(T& value) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
foo(T& value) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
foo(vector<T>& value) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_fundamental<T>::value>::type
foo(vector<vector<T>>& value) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main() {
    int a;
    vector<int> b;
    vector<vector<int>> c;
    ComplexClass d;
    char e;
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
    foo(d);
    foo(e);
}
```

Output:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type foo(T&) [with T = int; typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type = void]
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type foo(std::vector<_Tp>&) [with T = int; typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type = void]
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type foo(std::vector<std::vector<_Tp> >&) [with T = int; typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type = void]
typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value)>::type foo(T&) [with T = ComplexClass; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value)>::type = void]
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type foo(T&) [with T = char; typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<_Tp>::value>::type = void]
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
template <typename T> constexpr bool isType();
template <> constexpr bool isType<int>()  {return true;}
template <> constexpr bool isType<ComplexClass>() {return false;}
```

`isType<char>` exists even if definition is missing.

What you can do is to `delete` the function:

```
template <typename T> constexpr bool isType() = delete;
template <> constexpr bool isType<int>()  {return true;}
template <> constexpr bool isType<ComplexClass>() {return false;}
```

No warnings with gcc/clang: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee40ad83b0946479)

So `foo(e);` still doesn't match any overload.

I would use tag dispatching instead:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};
std::true_type isType(tag<int>);
std::false_type isType(tag<ComplexClass>);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5064bea99b07c40b)